# Is it possible to use gitHub source control on local machine ?

Tags: github

my programming language are c# ( visual studio ) and android ( android studio ) and i need some source control to use.

Is it possible to use gitHub as local disk source control ?

Comment: http://msysgit.github.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is a version control system that can be used for source code control.  It works on local filesystems as well as across networks.

GitHub is an online service that hosts Git repositories.  Git and GitHub are not the same thing.

https://git-scm.com/ is the homepage for the Git version control system.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 is the book "Pro Git" that includes information about how to set up a repository.

Comment: If you want a both a local repository and web interface like GitHub, you can use GitLab: https://about.gitlab.com/